# jQuery .not(this) not working

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to show item info in a list with jQuery. It's working great, but whenever I click an item that's already active, it will slideUp and SlideDown again. I want it to only slideUp and close.

That's why I tried using .not(this), but it is nog working, am I doing something wrong?

This is the code:

```
$('#MixIt .item').on('click', function(e){
    if(e.target.localName == 'div'){
        $('.item-body').not(this).slideUp();
        $(this).next('.item-body').slideToggle();
    }
});
```

Thanks!

**edit:**

Figured it out.

Was targeting 'this' but I need the .item-body of 'this'

*Code now is:*

```
$('#MixIt .item').on('click', function(e){
  var __this = $(this).next('.item-body');
  if(e.target.localName == 'div'){
    $('.item-body').not(__this).slideUp();
    $(this).next('.item-body').slideToggle();
  }
});
```

Comment: $('.item-body').not($(this)).slideUp();

Comment: You should provide HTML markup and replicates issue on jsFiddle. EDIT: is your issue fixed or what?!

Comment: @SomnathKharat Why? Passing a DOM element is valid as well.

Answer (score 3):

`this` is object of pure javascript and you are using `not` method of jquery with javascript object

```
$('#MixIt .item').on('click', function (e) {
    if (e.target.localName == 'div') {
        $('.item-body').not($(this)).slideUp();
        $(this).next('.item-body').slideToggle();
    }
});
```

Comment: `.not(this)` should be handled the same way

Comment: That would be true, but I also forgot that I didn't need to target 'this' but I needed the .item-body from 'this'.

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

**$(this)** should be there like this ,

```
       $('#MixIt .item').on('click', function(e){
        if(e.target.localName == 'div'){  
        $('.item-body').not($(this)).slideUp(); 
        $(this).next('.item-body').slideToggle();
       } 
      });
```

Comment: That would be true, but I also forgot that I didn't need to target 'this' but I needed the .item-body from 'this'.

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to add something to your parent.
Use that: `not($(this).parent())`

```
$('.item-body').not($(this).parent()).slideUp();
```